# Me pone siempre el mismo texto

Tags: c++, booleano

Tengo que hacer un programa que me diga si los primeros dos números al sumarse dan el tercer numero, soy bastante nuevo así que me gustaría explicaciones de por ejemplo el bool, ya que es la primera ves que lo uso, el problema es que cuando abro el programa, ponga lo que ponga me va a decir siempre el primer cartel, estoy seguro de que es algo del bool o del return.
Gracias.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

bool EsIgual(float n1, float n2, float n3);

int main (){
    float a,b,c;
    string igual;
    cout << "Digite tres numeros con decimales: " << endl;
    cin >> a; 
    cin >> b;
    cin >> c;
    igual = EsIgual(a,b,c);
    cout << igual << endl;
    return 0;
}
bool EsIgual(float n1, float n2, float n3)
{
    bool x,y,z;
    if (x + y == z) {
        cout << "La suma de los primeros dos numeros da como resultado el tercer numero." << endl;
    } else {
    cout << "La suma de los primeros dos numeros da como resultado el tercer numero." << endl;
    }
    return x,y,z;
}
```

Comment: Tienes que aprender a activar los avisos del tu compilador. Esto te ahorrara
muchas preguntas como esta.

Answer (score 1):

Para comenzar, debes tener claro como funciona los tipo de datos booleano, para explicarlo de manera simple estos tipos de datos almacenan valores **Verdadero** o **Falso**, son muy usados cuando quieres almacenar el valor de una condicional o una función de tipo booleano.
Ejemplo

```
2+3=5 (esto sería verdadero)
2+3=7 (esto sería falso)
```

Para tu caso la función `EsIgual` estas declarando que va retornar un valor de tipo booleano, entonces retornará verdadero o falso

Te comento los errores encontrados en tu código.

```
int main (){
    float a,b,c;
    string igual;//Declaras un string 
    cout << "Digite tres numeros con decimales: " << endl;
    cin >> a; 
    cin >> b;
    cin >> c;
//la variable igual es un string y la funcion *EsIgual* debe retornar un valor de tipo booleano, es decir verdadero o falso
    igual = EsIgual(a,b,c);
    cout << igual << endl;
    return 0;
}
bool EsIgual(float n1, float n2, float n3)
{
    bool x,y,z;//Declaras 3 variables que locales que no son necesarios
    if (x + y == z) {//x,y,z no tienen ningún valor inicial
        cout << "La suma de los primeros dos numeros da como resultado el tercer numero." << endl;
    } else {
    cout << "La suma de los primeros dos numeros da como resultado el tercer numero." << endl;
    }
    return x,y,z; //No puedes retornar valores númericos en una función que retorna booleano
}
```

Te comparto como debería ser tu código

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

bool EsIgual(float n1, float n2, float n3);

int main (){
    float a,b,c;
    bool igual;//Tienes que declarar una variable de tipo booleano
    cout << "Digite tres numeros con decimales: " << endl;
    cin >> a; 
    cin >> b;
    cin >> c;
    igual = EsIgual(a,b,c);//El valor verdadero o falso que retorna la función
    if(igual){ //comparamos 2+3=5 en este caso sería verdadero
        cout << "La suma de los primeros dos numeros da como resultado el tercer numero." << endl;
    }else //comparamos 2+3=7 sería falso
        cout << "La suma de los primeros dos numeros NO da como resultado el tercer numero." << endl;
        
    return 0;
}
bool EsIgual(float n1, float n2, float n3)
{    
    if ((n1 + n2) == n3) 
        return true;
    else return false;
}
```

Comment: En lugar del if, puedes retornar directamente `(n1+n2)==n3`.

Comment: Tienes razón, a veces cuando son nuevos no es conveniente abreviar porque después se confunden más

Answer (score 1):

> Me pone siempre el mismo texto

Pues claro, no importa si es verdadero o falso, imprimes la misma informacion:

```
    if (x + y == z) {
        cout << "La suma de los primeros dos numeros da como resultado el "
                "tercer numero."
             << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "La suma de los primeros dos numeros da como resultado el "
                "tercer numero."
             << endl;
    }
```

Si te das cuenta las 2 ramas del if son iguales.

#### Otros problemas

Las variables que estas usando en el if no tienen nada que ver con los
parametros que colocaste en la funcion, y estan sin inicializar.

```
    bool x, y, z;
```

---

Este return:

```
    return x, y, z;
```

Que se supone que hace eso?

Sea lo que tu esperaras que hiciera, ese va a usar el operador `,` y el ultimo
elemento se convertira implicitamente a un `bool`, eso es lo que retorna tu
funcion.